# MSMQ message consumer

Tags: logging, msmq, listeners

I have an application with many 'agents' which communicate through MSMQ queues. One of the agents puts a message on the queue and I am expecting the other one to consume the message but this does not happen. So the agent which is registered as a listener to that queue did not consume the message, but the message disappeared from the queue.
I there a way to se who consumed the message or what happened with it?

Thank you

**Update**
I've done some progress and I found where the message dissapears, but I much more confuse now. I have something like this:

```
private void queue_PeekCompleted(object sender, PeekCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    var queue = (MessageQueue)sender;

    Message message1 = queue.EndPeek(e);

    var transaction = new MessageQueueTransaction();
    transaction.Begin();
    try
    {
        var message2 = queue.Receive(transaction);
        // process the message
        transaction.Commit();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // some code here
    }
}
```

But message1.Id is different than message2.Id

I also tried 
`var message2 = queue.ReceiveById(message1.Id, transaction);` but it throws an exception...

Any ideas about what can happen between this two operations?

Comment: Configure source journaling: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12937306/how-to-enable-negative-source-journaling-while-sending-a-message-to-msmq

Comment: Also, enable and check the msmq event log on the receiving machine